# referencing a private variable from a static method in angular 2

Tags: angular

I've got a class that I want to have a static get method that refers to a private variable that is set from a service.  Here's what I have so far, but I'm getting hung up in circular logic.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserPermissions {
    private static _userPermissions: PermissionsModel;
    private static get userPermissions(): PermissionsModel {
        if (!UserPermissions._userPermissions) {
            UserPermissions.setPermissions();
        }
    }

    private static set UserPermissions() {
        let id = SessionStorage.getItem(SS_USER_ID); 

        // How do I setup profileService? 
        // Normally, I would have a constructor that would be:
        // constructor( private profileService: ProfileService ) {}
        // and the class would have @Component({ providers: [ProfileService] })

        profileService.getPermissions(id).subscribe(
            permissions => UserPermissions._userPermissions = permissions;
        );
    }

    public static hasPermissions(permissionCode: string): boolean {
        let index = UserPermissions.userPermissions().permissions
            .findIndex(permission => permission.code == permissionCode);
        return index >= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't use `static`.

Comment: **NEVER USE STATIC** one fine day you will have sleepless night with some defect under your name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm hearing you right, you are asking how to inject a service in another service?
If so, you can make a constructor injection, as long as the component from which you use the service, has it injected.

In other words: if you have a `ComponentA` which injects a service called `serviceB`(using `providers`), then all children of `ComponentA` can get the `serviceB` instance using constructor injection as you commented in your code (`constructor( private profileService: ProfileService ) {}`).

I will recommend reading the [Angular architecture](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#dependency-injection) section about dependency injection.

I hope it helps and that it was i fact what you were asking for.